# PdfSharp Incomplete data displayed

Tags: c#, pdf

I'm generating PDF using PdfSharp in C#.net

In my UAT, pdf is generating nicely

But on the production server, Incomplete Data is displayed towards the footer of PDF

My code goes as below

```
string strData = File.ReadAllText(strSourceFilepath);

PdfDocument Document = new PdfDocument();
PdfPage Pdfpage = Document.AddPage();

System.Drawing.Size size = new System.Drawing.Size(700, 1000);
System.Drawing.Color color = System.Drawing.Color.White;
System.Drawing.Image image = HtmlRender.RenderToImage(strData, size, color);

XGraphics xGraphics = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(Document.Pages[0]);
xGraphics.DrawImage(image, 0, 0);
// Document.Pages.Add(Pdfpage);
string strFilename = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(strSourceFilepath);
strFilePath = strDestinationFilepath + "\\" + strFilename + ".pdf";
Document.Save(strFilePath);
Document.Close();
return strFilePath;
```

Comment: Please supply a sample broken output PDF

Comment: Sorry!! confidential data